# Did not understand these solidity codes

Tags: solidity

In the code:

```
  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
      return interfaceId == type(MyInterface).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }
```

In this code i did not understand 2 thing:

1. How `type(MyInterface).interfaceId` works?
2. How `return interfaceId == type(MyInterface).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);` works?

please explain these 2 codes.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of EIP-165, please check out the [official standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165).

It will simply return true if the supplied interface is either type(MyInterface).interfaceId or super.supportsInterface(interfaceId), meaning it calls supportsInterface on the contracts that this contract overrides. If either is true this function returns true.

Comment: what is type(interface)?

Comment: Every contract defines its own type. For a contract C you can use type(C) to access type information about the contract

Comment: If you want more explanation for this. you can check out the ERC165 section of this article, commenting it here because it won't be a good choice to put the article's link in the answers section  https://www.zaryabs.com/ethereum-token-standards-part-erc721/